# SetDeadline for golang tcp connection

Tags: go, tcp

If I set a deadline to a tcp connection, and I read and write it successfully, and I keep it alive for subsequence communction, does the deadline affect the next reading/writing? Should I set deadline to 0 for a connection after reading from/writing to it?

Comment: I am not go-expert, what does the doc say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Conn interface also has deadline settings; either for the connection as a whole (`SetDeadLine()`) or specific to read or write calls (`SetReadDeadLine()` and `SetWriteDeadLine()`).
>
> Note that the deadlines are fixed points in (wallclock) time. Unlike timeouts, they don’t reset after a new activity. **Each activity on the connection must therefore set a new deadline.**

Emphasis mine.

From https://appliedgo.net/networking/ (second google search result).

Comment: I get it, thank you.The timer won't stop until I set a new value to it, right?

Comment: Yes, **Each activity on the connection must therefore set a new deadline.** Good luck.

Comment: sorry，i forget it，i have accepted it now. Thank you for your answer